# I have a simple class that grabs the last two digits of the current year. I need to make this class Invocable, how do I do this?

Tags: apex, invocable-method, invocablevariable

I need to just make this class an Invocable method so that I can grab the last two digits of the year from this class and add it to a text field on another object using a flow.

This is the code from the simple class:

```
global with sharing class Invocable_GetCurrentYearLastTwo {

    @InvocableMethod(
        label = 'Pull Two Digit Year'
        description = 'Method to Extract Current Year'
    )
    global static List<LastTwoYear> GetLastTwoYear() {      
         List<LastTwoYear> LastTwoYear = new List<LastTwoYear>();
        integer year =  Date.Today().Year();
        string LastTwo=string.valueof(year).right(2);
        string TwoDigitYear= string.valueof(LastTwo);
        System.debug(LastTwoYear);
        return LastTwoYear;
    }
            
    global class LastTwoYear {
        @InvocableVariable(
            label = 'LastTwoYear'
            description = 'Variable to store Base URL'
        )
        global String LastTwoYear;
    }          
}
```

After looking at invocable methods I understand it needs to be in a List but for this class I only ever need to return a single value, being the last two digits of the year as a string or integer. What is the easiest way for a flow to be able to see the return value of this class / or how can I make it an invocable method?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You make a method invocable by adding [the `@InvocableMethod` annotation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_classes_annotation_InvocableMethod.htm) to the method signature.

It also needs to be a static method. The `global` visibility modifier is discouraged unless you're making a managed package (`public` works just fine unless you want people who install the managed package to be able to use the method themselves, outside of the managed package).

Getting around the "need to return a list or list of lists" bit just requires a bit of a shift in mindset. A list doesn't need to contain multiple items, it can contain a single item (or no items). If you know you'll only ever have one element, you can loop over it (in your flow) and set another flow variable inside of that loop. Now you have an individual flow variable that you can use.

+edit:
You can use a custom inner class with an invocable variable, but you shouldn't need to go quite that far. You should be able to return a `List<String>`. This code could be shortened further, but I'm making it more verbose here so I can explain a few things better.

```java
    @InvocableMethod(
        label = 'Pull Two Digit Year'
        description = 'Method to Extract Current Year'
    )
    // Use public instead of global unless you know you need to use global
    // General code style has
    // - classes and types using TitleCase
    // - methods and variables using camelCase
    // - collections (lists, sets, maps) having a plural name
    // - variable names being descriptive
    public static List<String> getLastTwoYear() {      
        List<String> results = new List<String>();

        // Instead of trying to do string manipulation, you can use
        // Datetime's format() method to do the work
        // It uses Java's SimpleDateFormat. 'yy' = 2 digit year.
        String twoDigitYear = Datetime.now().format('yy');

        // .add() is used to add items into a list
        results.add(twoDigitYear);

        return results;
    }
```

If you need to make your example work with your extra inner class, then you'll want to make your life easier by getting rid of the *name shadowing*.

```java
    @InvocableMethod(
        label = 'Pull Two Digit Year'
        description = 'Method to Extract Current Year'
    )
    public static List<YearHolder> getLastTwoYear() {
        // Using the class name as the variable name is likely to
        //   cause issues. Best to just use a different name here.
        // Re-using the name of anything is called "shadowing"
        List<YearHolder> results = new List<YearHolder>();

        Integer year = Date.today().year();
        string yearWith2Digits = String.valueof(year).right(2);
        
        // Gotta make an instance of your other class so you can then
        //   put data into it.
        // This could be done in one line here if you had a class constructor
        //   ...but it's simple enough and it's either a line in this
        //   method or a line in your inner class
        YearHolder yearResult = new YearHolder();
        yearResult.twoDigitYear = yearWith2Digits;

        // Same as with the last example, you need to add data to your list
        //   before you return the list.
        results.add(yearResult);
        
        return results;
    }

    // Again, use public unless you know you need to use global
    public class YearHolder {
        @InvocableVariable(
            label = 'YearHolder'
            description = 'Variable to store 2 digit year'
        )
        public String twoDigitYear;
    }
```

Comment: Hey thank you this makes sense! Sorry am new to this. I have edited my original post to reflect some new code, and now I have this and Im still not returning the simple string however, am I supposed to create a for loop to contain that string as part of the list?

Comment: @Zzz I've updated my answer. You don't need a for loop in your code here. Shadowing aside, the thing you were missing is that you were never adding data to the list you were returning. The only looping that you should need to do here is in your flow (so you can get access to the single piece of data in the list and use it elsewhere in your flow).

Comment: Hey, thanks so much for the update it helped out tremendously and the flow worked out perfectly !